# VSTS Automate License Purchases

Tags: azure-devops, azure-marketplace, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there any way to automatically purchase new licenses for VSTS users? There's API's for adding users and adding entitlements, but I can't find anything for buying new licenses.

Comment: What kind of licenses do you want to purchase?  Visual Studio Enterprise/Pro licenses?

Comment: Just express/basic for VSTS users.

Comment: Perhaps then you could explain more of your use case?, to me this doesn't seem like something you'd want to automate.

Comment: No automated way to do it.

Comment: @raterus The number of users on this instance of VSTS changes frequently. So it's pretty tedious to go through and have to buy a new license every time a user is added.

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t he API to buy the new license, you can change another’s’ access level to Stakeholder and change the new added user’s access level to Basic if someone do not need the basic access level.

[User Entitlements - Update User Entitlement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement)

On the other hand, you just need to add user to VSTS who has the Visual Studio Enterprise subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I scanned through the full list of APIs supported by Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation Services (TFS) documented [Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview).  AFAIk, there is no API exposed to automatically purchase new express/basic licenses for VSTS users.
I concur with raterus. Can you please elaborate on your use case and we can attempt to prescribe an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

The use case: Azure DevOps (ADO) bills you directly for reserved license space. I.e. I can buy space for 2000 basic licenses within an ADO-organization and even if no one is active (utilizing a basic license) my company gets billed for the 2000 inactive users per  month. So as a ADO admin you buy a little license space extra for new users that join, when you run out of it you buy a little extra space again.

I am currently in the process where we slowly ramp up to approximately 4000+ ADO users over a couple of years. People are allowed to join the ADO-org through AD group membership, the moment they become active they take a basic license (if there is licensespace) otherwise they get assigned a stakeholder license. Which you have to correct by hand, mostly after user is baffled as they can't clone the git repo after having carefully followed the readme.

All in all a cumbersome manual environment, please allow me to automate the user management. Or change the license model to not bill unusued license space, then I can set the cap to 4000 and I am fine.

**What is  possible**

- detecting low license space, with a cronned pipeline we can send an alert to remediate
- adding removing users and licenses, typically run at the last day of the month to remove inactive users (for them invisible as they get the license back once they return through their AD group membership)